# iOS 7 splash screen re-sizes during launch

Tags: cordova, ios7

I have a Cordova based app and due to the iOS7 status bar that is over the app, I've re-sized the webview:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // View defaults to full size.  If you want to customize the view's size, or its subviews (e.g. webView),
    // you can do so here.
    //Lower screen 20px on ios 7
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
        CGRect viewBounds = [self.webView bounds];
        viewBounds.origin.y = 18;
        viewBounds.size.height = viewBounds.size.height - 18;
        self.webView.frame = viewBounds;
    }
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

The problem now is that the splash screen starts in full screen but when the status bar appears the splash screen re-sizes.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: after changing the size to 2048 x 1536, the splash screen image is pushed about 10 pixels down...

Answer (score 0):

Re-sizing the image to 2048 x 1575 seems to do the trick...